# How to personalize contact first name in marketing cloud email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, contact, marketing-cloud-connect

I am sending marketing cloud email to 1 record in sales cloud which consist of 2 contacts.
i am using content builder to send email but personalizing first name using ampscript (%%FirstName%%) is not working.
i need to personalize contact first name.
So, any other way to achieve this.

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted, so other users can see your problem has been resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The personalization string `%%FirstName%%` only works if the subscribers attributes/preferences are correctly set. In order to use your data from Sales Cloud you need to link the Sales Cloud field to the subscriber attribute or query the first name using the AMPscript `Lookup`-function.

Mapping the attribute fields works like this:

> 1. In the Marketing Cloud, navigate to Email Studio.
> 2. Click Subscribers.
> 3. Click Profile Management.
> 4. Select an existing attribute or create a new one.
> 5. Click the Salesforce tab within the attribute properties.
> 6. Select the field to map the attribute.
> 7. Repeat to map each attribute to a field in the Sales or Service Cloud.
>
> (Source: [Marketing Cloud Connect - Map Attribute Fields](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/setting_up_the_connector/map_attribute_fields/))

**Related documentation:**

- [Marketing Cloud Connect - Map Attribute Fields](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/setting_up_the_connector/map_attribute_fields/)
- [AMPscript - Lookup-function](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookup/#Lookup)